# Can こんちゃbe used as a slang form of こんにちわ?

Tags: word-choice, slang, internet-slang

It was a typed response to me after I greeted the person in an email. I am wondering if it is a slang term or if it has a different meaning. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんちゃ is slang that have more friendly meaning.
Almost there is no difference in the point of meaning.
But you don't have to use it at first time, or for people on higher position.

In my opinion, I don't like this expression and I don't use it.
Because it contains also foolish sense.

Thanks.